# which product category to choose in magento

Tags: magento

I am newbie in magento. I am creating a **product** that is basically a **video file**. I want that whenever the user clicks  on that product he is asked to buy different file sizes for that video like HD version, Sd version. So I thought to create a simple prduct with custom options of file size.

**But I want your suggestion that whether I should create it as a downloadable product,  configurable or simple product with custom options.**

Basically I am confused as it needs to be a **downloadable product** where the different sizes video files are located at server for download or it can be **simple** product also just click and buy the particular product of file size or it cabn be **configurable** also.

Please suggest.Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your product is meant to be downloaded I would hazard a guess that it should be a **downloadable product**. The downloadable type allows for different versions/copies/sizes of files to be selected, try it and see.

Comment: Thanx for answering. Could you please tell me how to add different versions for a single downloadable product.

Comment: Just upload each version of the product. [Here are some instructions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/catalog/create_a_downloadable_product).

Comment: what I got to know is that u can add different links for the different versions but I want that the customer should select the version from the drop down the same way we do by adding custom options to simple product and then purchase the associated link for that version.

Comment: There is a setting for "Links can be purchased separately". Setting this to "Yes" gives customers an option. New downloadable products already have this set to "Yes".

Comment: Thanx. I will try to work that way. Please have a look at this question  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469684/unable-to-purchase-on-downloadable-products-in-magento I am in urgent need of an answer for it.